# iOS app crashes due to Error Domain=UILaunchStoryboardErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

Runs fine on xcode builds, crashes at TestFlight. 
Log from device:

```
Fatal error generating launch image for xxx.xxx.xxx: 
Error Domain=UILaunchStoryboardErrorDomain Code=2 
"Error loading: [<NSObject 0x1262580b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key animationLoader." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error loading: 
[<NSObject 0x1262580b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key animationLoader., 
UILaunchStoryboardClientBundleIdentifier=xxx.xxx.xxx}
```

Could not find any documentation for this error. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've assigned the right class to the ViewController and try to delete and reset your outlets.